# Writing a generic method for .Field<T>() in Linq to DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, linq-to-objects

I have been attempting to write a reusable generic method for lookups on a `DataTable`. What I have so far:

```
private static IEnumerable<DataRow> GetRow<FType>(string Tablename, 
    string Fieldname, FType Match)
{
    var result = from row in dataSet.Tables[Tablename].AsEnumerable()
                 where row.Field<FType>(Fieldname) == Match
                 select row;

    return result;
}
```

However, we don't like the **`row.Field<FType>(Fieldname) == Match`**.

Any ideas on what I'm suppose to do to fix this? I get: Operator '==' cannot be applied to FType and FType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `== Match` with `.Equals(Match)` and you should be good. I've thrown in a null check in case the values could be null.

```
private static IEnumerable<DataRow> GetRow<FType>(string Tablename, string Fieldname, FType Match)
{
    var result = from row in dataSet.Tables[Tablename].AsEnumerable()
                 where row.Field<FType>(Fieldname) != null
                 && row.Field<FType>(Fieldname).Equals(Match)
                 select row;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for including the null check. Odd how the `!=` is okay but can't use `==`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the equality check. You could also add an overload where the comparer could be specified explicitly.

```
private static IEnumerable<DataRow> GetRow<FType>(string Tablename, string Fieldname, FType match)
{
    IEqualityComparer<FType> comp = EqualityComparer<TField>.Default;
    return dataSet.Tables[Tablename]
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(comp.Equals(row.Field<FType>(Fieldname), match));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .Equals() should do the trick. Another option would be to pass in an IComparer or a delegate Comparer for custom comparing

Comment: Nice suggestions, but `.Equals` means you've got to cater for nulls on the left of the dot, but we don't know whether `FType` is a reference or value type and whether it *can* be null or not. You could get around that by providing two seperate methods with different generic constraints, but that feels pretty ugly to me.

Comment: @Alex, the two different methods would need to differ by more than just the constraints, because those are not part of the signature. But you can include a null check safely in the single method. `where row.Field<FType>(Fieldname) != null && [other criteria]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator overloading:

```
public static bool operator ==(FType a, FType b)
{
    // Your code
    // Check here if A and B are equal
}
```